# How to resize text for mobile responsiveness

Tags: html

I am trying to create my website and input a short animation of text sliding every 0.4 seconds to change to another text. It's like an image gallery, but just text instead. I put this html code together from ws3school hence, some of the code inside might not make sense but it still runs perfectly fine.

I do not know how to code and I am just trying to make sense of what I see, some of the code below may seem a little inappropriate or weird to be there, I'm just trying to make it all work.

**The issue I have is that it is not mobile-friendly**, so when I open the website on a smaller screen, the font size does not change accordingly. I think I managed to fix the border size but not the font size. Can someone help me?

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    .div1 {
      max-width: 460px;
      height: 170px;
      padding: 40px;
      border: 1px solid black;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 65px;
      font-family: courier;
    }
    /* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
    
    @media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
      .text {
        max-font-size: 20px
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="div1">
    <div class="mySlides w3-container w3-xlarge w3-transparent">
      <p>marketer</p>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides w3-container w3-xlarge w3-transparent">
      <p>creator</p>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides w3-container w3-xlarge w3-transparent">
      <p>innovator</p>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides w3-container w3-xlarge w3-transparent">
      <p>collaborator</p>
    </div>

    <script>
      var slideIndex = 0;
      carousel();

      function carousel() {
        var i;
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
          x[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        slideIndex++;
        if (slideIndex > x.length) {
          slideIndex = 1
        }
        x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
        setTimeout(carousel, 400);
      }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: There is no CSS property `max-font-size`. You just use `font-size`

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    .div1 {
        font-size: 20px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm doesn't work, the text isn't resized when I open it on mobile :/

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
div.example {
  max-width: 460px;
  height: 170px;
  padding: 40px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 65px;
  font-family: courier;
 }


  @media screen and (min-width: 601px) {
  div.example {
     font-size: 65px;
  }
 }

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  div.example {
    font-size: 30px;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="example">
      <p>marketer</p>
    </div>

    <div class="example">
      <p>creator</p>
    </div>

    <div class="example">
      <p>innovator</p>
    </div>

    <div class="example">
      <p>collaborator</p>
    </div>
   </div>

<script>
var slideIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("example");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none"; 
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > x.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 
  setTimeout(carousel, 400); 
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I honestly don't know what I did, but I managed to make it work. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You can use relative size like **vw** to make it responsive. In combination with **calc** you can say that minimal font size should be for example 20px and for bigger screens it should be bigger thanks the **vw** unit.

```
font-size: calc(20px + 0.4vw);
```

You can use this outside the media query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```js
var slideIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > x.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(carousel, 400);
}
```

```css
.div1 {
  max-width: 460px;
  height: 170px;
  padding: 40px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 65px;
  font-family: courier;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .div1 p {
    font-size: 20px
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="div1">
    <div class="mySlides">
      <p>marketer</p>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <p>creator</p>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <p>innovator</p>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <p>collaborator</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I still couldn't make it work with yours, but your code helped to tidy mine a little. I managed to make it work by using one of the codes from w3schools, check it out below! Thanks for your help though!